# Need help making this button into a circle

Tags: ios, swift

We have a rectangle box which is a button - the inside circle is an image. The button is stretched because of the constraints( stackViews)

The Button is 197 width   by   77 height

[image]

We tried turning this into a circle but it did not work - we used this code

```
// Mehtod 1
    circleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * circleButton.bounds.size.width

    // Method 2
    circleButton.layer.cornerRadius = (circleButton.imageView?.bounds.size.width)! * 0.5
```

We are trying to turn it into a circle at runtime. So it can be the same size as the image which is the circle. Thanks for the help

Comment: What's your question? What results do you get with the methods you've tried?

Comment: You can do that by using mask of layer,I will post the codes after I get off the bus.

Answer (score 0):

```html
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TimoonPumba.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(roundButtonDidTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//width and height should be same value
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT);

//Clip/Clear the other pieces whichever outside the rounded corner
button.clipsToBounds = YES;

//half of the width
button.layer.cornerRadius = ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT/2.0f;
button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: The question it is tagged with Swift

Comment: oops my bad didnt see that

Comment: @Joséph Flames This works if the button is the same width and height but my button is 197 X 7. any solutions for that?

Comment: use the image AS the button is my suggestion i used to do that back when  i used theos but it was objc not swift